# I can't get paging to work with php and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I modify the question because I have probably explained myself badly. I modify the question because I have probably explained myself badly.
This is my htaccess file. all requests are handled by the core.php file

```
RewriteEngine ON
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex home.php

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml ./sitemap.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ core.php [QSA,L]
```

the core.php file, fetch the url and check if it corresponds to an article or a category.

```
<?php include './include/include.php'; ?>

<?php 
$url = basename(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$cleanUrl = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$st2 = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM sb_article WHERE url = '$cleanUrl'");
while($recordArt = $st2->fetch()){
    $artUrl = $recordArt['url'];
    }
if($artUrl !== $cleanUrl){
$st = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM sb_category WHERE categoria = '$cleanUrl'");
while($recordCat = $st->fetch()){
    $catTit = $recordCat['categoria'];
    }
}

switch($cleanUrl){
    case $artUrl:
        single();
    break;
    case $catTit:
        archive();
    break;
    case "contatti":
        echo "sono una la pagina contatti";
    break;
    default:
    echo "articolo non trovato";
    break;
}



function single(){
    $urlArticle = basename(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    require './include/dbConnFront.php';
    include './include/var-null.php';
    require './classes/class.single.php';

    $single= new showArticle($urlArticle, $PDO);
    $showSingle = $single->single();

    if($showSingle !== NULL){ foreach($showSingle as $list){
        $id = $list['id'];
        $titolo = $list['titolo'];
        $testo = html_entity_decode($list['testo']);
        $descrizione = $list['descrizione'];
        $categoria = $list['categoria'];
        $url = $list['url'];
        $img = $list['img'];
        $data = $list['data'];}}

    require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/single.php");
}


function archive(){
    $url_archive = basename(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $urlCompleto = "catogory/".$url_archive;
    require './include/dbConnFront.php';
    include './include/var-null.php';
 

  
require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/archive.php");

}


?>
```

if it is a category. The archive.php file executes the query and prints the result with the list of articles.

```
<?php
$url_archive = basename(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$x_page = 8;
$page = 1;
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){$page = filter_var($_GET['page'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);}

    $rowsCount = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM sb_article");
    $allRows = $rowsCount->rowCount();

    $all_page = ceil($allRows / $x_page);
    $first = ($page - 1) * $x_page;

    $result_sql = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM sb_article LIMIT $first, $x_page");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
     $nr = $result_sql->rowCount();
     $i = 2;
     if($nr != 0){
     for($x = 0; $x < $nr; $x++){        
     while($row = $result_sql->fetch()){
     $titolo = $row['titolo'];
     $id = $row['id'];
     $categoria = $row['categoria'];
     $data = $row['data'];
    
     $i++;
                
     if($i % 2 == 0){
     $bg_row = "row-grey";
     }   else{
     $bg_row = "row-white";
     }
                                 
     echo "
     <div class='container-name-article ". $bg_row ." clearfix'>
     <div class='name-article'><a href='sb-modify-article.php?". $id ."'>". $titolo ."</a></div>
     <div class='btn-delete-article'><a href='sb-conf-delete-article.php?". $id ."'>Elimina</a></div>
     </div>
     <div class='info-list-article  ". $bg_row ."'>
     <span class='categoria-list'><b>Categoria: </b>". $categoria ."<span> <span class='data-list'><b>Pubblicato il: </b>". $data ."<span>
     </div>
     ";
    
     }
     }}//if
     ?>

<div class="pagination-list-article">
 <?php 
  if ($all_page > 1){
  if ($page > 1){
  echo "<span class='text-pagination'><a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?page=" . ($page - 1) . "\">";
  echo "Indietro</a></span>&nbsp;";
                                        }
  for ($p=1; $p<=$all_page; $p++) {
  if ($p == $page) echo "<span class='nr-no-pagination'>" . $p . "</span>&nbsp;";
  else { 
  echo "<span class='nr-pagination'><a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?page=" . $p . "\">" . $p . "</a></span>&nbsp;";
       } 
       }
       if ($all_page > $page){
       echo "<span class='text-pagination'><a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?page=" . ($page + 1) . "\">";
                                          echo "Avanti</a></span>";
                                        } 
                                      }
                                ?>                            
                            </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

So far so good, the problem starts when I click on the pagination link. In this case, I am redirected back to the core.php page and the url changes to core.php? Page = 2. So it doesn't find any matches. in addition, even if I manually type categoryname? page = 2, I am always redirected to the core.php page resulting in an error. How can I solve? Unfortunately I don't know htaccess, so I'm sure I'll have something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

remove the .php extension, your htaccess will take care of the extension.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with htaccess. could you explain me how to do it?

Comment: the problem is that all pages are handled by the core.php page. So clicking on forward or back the url will be core.php? Page = 2. Instead it should be namecategory.php? Page = 2.

Comment: you got a part of the code where you echo <a href='sb-modify-article.php?"> remove the .php extension, because of htacces you won't need to declare the extension anymore.

Comment: unfortunately this is not my problem. I have edited the main question to try to explain myself better by providing more details.

Comment: Did u try to remove "RewriteRule ^ core.php [QSA,L]" From the .htaccess file?